# Downloading not stops on AsynchTask even on pressing the back button

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I am downloading pdf file in AsynchTask, so as it downloading the file, my progress dialog is getting update. However Problem is that if i press the back button than my alert box gets pop up and the downloading gets stop in background. I want that it should continue its downloading even after alert dialog gets called or pause the download once alert gets pop up and continue downloading once if i click the cancel button of alert dialog.

Here is a snippet,

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
 switch (id)
 {
  case progress_bar_type:
  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
  pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
  pDialog.setMax(100);
  pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
  pDialog.setCancelable(true);
  pDialog.show();
  pDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() 
  {
   @Override
   public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
   {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
     running = false;

        AlertDialog.Builder  alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        AlertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Ariisto");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you Want to Cancel the Download ?");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
        @Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
{
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                File externalFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"downloadedfile.pdf");
                                externalFile.delete();
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                running = false;
                                Log.d("External File", "DELETED");
                                pDialog.setProgress(0);
                                count = 2;


                            }
                        });
                        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
                                running = true;
                                count = 0;
                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();

                            alert.show();

                    }

                    return false;

                }
            });


            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */




        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
            publishProgress(""+(int)(0));
            running = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.d("------------","iNSIDE ON CANCELLED METHOD");

            super.onCancelled();
        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... file_url) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int count;
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(file_url[0]);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.pdf");


                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while (   ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) && (running == true)  ) 
                {




                    total += count;

                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Error: ", " "+e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) 
        {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
        {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            if(running == true){
                dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
                // Displaying downloaded image into image view
                // Reading image path from sdcard
                String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.pdf";
                // setting downloaded into image view
                Log.d(imagePath, "show file");
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"downloadedfile.pdf");
                Uri external = Uri.fromFile(file);

                viewPdf(external);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Pressing Back on an Activity should NOT stop the AsyncTask, unless you cancel it. You're probably better off with a Service though.

Comment: It is not stopping the download i mean AsynchTask is still performing its operation. I need that it should pause the process when user press the back button and resume its operation once user click on cancel button of alert box.

Comment: The download operation starts in the background thread and once the operation start in doInBackground() you cannot "pause" it. You will have to cancel the task and start it again after button click.

Answer (score 0):

I have a requirement very similar to this. A user will click on a listItem and an AsyncTask will start downloading it, and then displays it when done. Should the user tap the back-button before the download is complete, an alert dialog is displayed asking whether to abort the download. Should the download complete WHILE that dialog is displayed, it simply dismisses the dialog and finishes that activity. I don't have time to pull and sanitize the code, but the pattern is as follows:

The activity has two private fields:

```
private DownloadTask downloader = null;
private AlertDialog dlgCancel = null;
```

in onBackPressed:

```
if( downloader != null ) {
    dlgCancel =....
    dlgCancel.show();
} else
    finish();
```

in the DownloadTask's onPostExecute:

```
if( isCancelled() ) {
    ... dismiss the download
} else { 
    if( dlgCancel == null ) {
        ... handle the download here ...
    } else {
        dlgCancel.dismiss();
        dlgCancel = null;
        Activity.finish();
    }
}
```

and finally, in the onClick for the Abort-Download button:

```
downloader.cancel( true );
Activity.finish();
```

Note that you'll need to watch for isCancelled() in your AsyncTask's doInBackground() so that you can react as quickly as possible. Some operations won't return immediately.